# Почему с итераторами не сортируется и вылетает?

Tags: stl, vector, c++

Помогите разобраться с итераторами. Почему с итераторами не сортируется и вылетает?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <conio.h>

#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    vector <int> arr;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        arr.push_back(rand() % 9);
    }
    cout << "Вектор заполнен случайными числами!" << endl;
    //начальный элемент
    vector<int>::iterator it_begin = arr.begin();
    //текущий
    vector <int>::iterator current;
    vector <int>::iterator next;

        cout << "######################" << endl;
        for (current = arr.begin(); current != arr.end(); current++)
        {
            cout << *current << endl;
        }
        cout << "######################" << endl;

        int temp;
        vector<int>::iterator iteri;
        vector<int>::iterator iterj;
        iteri = arr.begin();
        iterj = arr.end() - 1;
        cout << *iterj;

        for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        {
            while (iteri != arr.end())
            {
                while (iterj>iteri)
                {
                    if (*(iterj - 1)>*iterj)
                    {
                        temp = *iterj;
                        *(iterj - 1) = *iterj;
                        *iterj = temp;
                    }
                    iterj++;
                }
                iteri++;
            }
        }
        /*
    for (current = arr.begin(); current<arr.end(); ++current)
            for (next = current + 1; next < arr.end(); ++next)
                if (current>next)
                {
                    temp = *current;
                    *current = *next;
                    *next = temp;
                }
*/

    cout << "######################" << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в строках

```
*temp = *current;
*current = *next;
*next = *temp;
```

Вы пытаетесь использовать итератор не для того, для чего он нужен.

Пишите так

```
temp = *current;
*current = *next;
*next = temp;
```

Либо добавьте `#include <algorithm>` и пишите так

```
swap(*current, *next);
```

Comment: @KoVadim  error C2440: =: невозможно преобразовать "std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<int>>>" в "int" 
error C2679: бинарный "=": не найден оператор, принимающий правый операнд типа "int" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует) 

Но ведь и так не то.

Comment: @KoVadim
как то циклы не так пишу?

Comment: Так объявите temp правильно. Это уже просто int.

Answer (score 0):

Можно [`iter_swap()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap) использовать. Примеры реализации классических алгоритмов сортировки на современном C++: [How to implement classic sorting algorithms in modern C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24650626).